# how to pass single file not list of files

Tags: bash, regex, pipe

I am running this command

```
while IFS= read -r file;do split -l 20000 -d "$file" "$file";done < file.list.txt
```

now my problem is that this accepts as input a list of files (file.list) which looks like

```
job1
job2
```

I would need the command to accept a single input file...but If i write

```
while IFS= read -r file;do split -l 20000 -d "$file" "$file";done < job1
```

only get the file printed to standard out. Can somebody tell me how I make that command accept a single file, not a file list.

Answer (score 1):

What can I say? Simply run:

```
split -l 20000 -d "job1" "job1"
```

That's all.

Or:

```
file="job1"; split -l 20000 -d "$file" "$file"
```

---

The command `read` reads the entries in `file.list.txt` and executes `split -l 20000 -d "$file" "$file"` for each of them.

In your case:

```
split -l 20000 -d "job1" "job1"
split -l 20000 -d "job2" "job2"
```